# How to solve the minization problem with $Z^{T}Z=I$

Tags: optimization

I have the following problem
$$\underset{Z}{\min}\left\|X-AZBH\right\|_F^2+\left\|H-B^{T}Z^{T}A^{T}X\right\|\\
\text{subject to } Z^{T}Z=I$$

How to solve the variable $Z$?

Comment: Make a Lagrange functional where the constraint is added with a Lagrange multiplier (matrix). Then refresh yourself on trace algebra.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, you could expand this into an answer, I think.

Comment: You could add details on what are the shapes of all your matrices.

Comment: Is the second term really just the norm, not its square? In any case, what matrix norm is it?

Comment: The first term (with the Frobenius norm) is a weighted orthogonal Procrustes problem (WOPP). In general there may not be a unique solution for $Z$, and iterative methods must be used. See here for example: https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:144340/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: Yes, there may not be a unique solution for $\bf{Z}$ and I use a Lagrange function where the constraint is added with a Lagrange multiplier. Get the function: $\underset{Z}{min}\left\|X-AZBH\right\|_F^2+\left\|H-B^{T}Z^{T}A^{T}X\right\|_F^2+\beta tr(Z^{T}Z-I)$. Then take the derivative of $Z$ to zero, $(A^{T}XX^{T}A+2\beta A^{T}A)ZBB^{T}+A^{T}AZBHH^{T}B^{T}=A^{T}XH^{T}B^{T}$. And how to ensure the $Z^{T}Z=I$

Comment: @tjufan  Construct $Z$ from an _unconstrained_ matrix $U$ of the same size
$$Z = U(U^TU)^{-1/2} \quad\implies\quad Z^TZ = I$$
Then calculate the gradient wrt $U$. You will probably not be able to solve the zero-gradient condition analytically, but you can use the gradient in a descent method to find the optimal $U$ numerically, from which you can recover the optimal $Z.\;$